# Unit testing classes that have online functionality

Tags: unit-testing, junit

When unit testing functions of a class that has private functions that require online functionality. How would one go about testing it?

For example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int methodA()
    {
         int val = goOnlineToGetVal();

         return val;
    }

    private int goOnlineToGetVal()
    {
        CloudService c = new CloudService();
        int oval = c.getValueFromService();
        return oval;
    }
}
```

If I were to test function: 'methodA()' it would attempt to use 'goOnlineToGetVal()' which would in turn try to go online however, if this test was done without functionality. How would I go about 100% Class coverage without going online?

Comment: Does your method just call the cloud api, or does it do additional work as well?

Comment: Related reading: [Is mocking for unit testing appropriate in this scenario?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/166913/22815)

Comment: Dependency Injection ?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`new CloudService()`

And there's your problem.

Modern OO design recommends that this sort of dependency be [passed in](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) rather than constructed directly. This can be passed into the function itself, or to the class at construction time. It could also be grabbed or aggregated by an Inversion of Control container if that sort of complexity is warranted.

At that point, it becomes fairly trivial to pass in a mock/fake service to provide you with your "online" data during testing. Better yet, it allows your software to be sufficiently flexible, so that you can quickly adapt should some (governmental?) client comes along and doesn't want to use the cloud for their values. Or you want to dump one cloud provider for another. Or...

Comment: I think I just got a lot closer to understanding what the heck Dependency Injection is.

Comment: Where is the best place to create all the instances that my application needs? As close to the top of my application as possible? You can only apply dependency injection so far; at some point you'll need to create the instances yourself instead of having them passed as arguments.

Comment: @Paul - It depends. In my experience, applications very often look like binary trees - one class/function/module glues two together to provide some more complex behavior. One of those "glue" classes is the one that specifies the concrete implementation, which in turn is used by something above that glues it with something else, which in turn... until you eventually get to your entrypoint that glues the big pieces together coherently. The "best" place is the place that lets your code do what it needs to do, without making it do or know about things it shouldn't. It will vary.

Comment: @Paul Usually your application is divided between a "library", which is directly tested and should use this kind of dependency injection, and application-specific code. The latter usually boils down to some GUI, some web service or some command line interface that directly calls the library with user-supplied data. Essentially, application-specific code will create the concrete implementations that the dependency-injected library expects.

Comment: @Paul Take a look at IoC containers like Castle Windsor, StructureMap, Ninject and Unity. They are by no means the only way to do dependency injection, but they can be very informative in terms of thinking about constructing an object graph, from the top down

Comment: @BenAaronson - Bleh. I disagree. IoC containers are misinformative. They're ubiquitously abused and overused and the wrong end of the curve to start learning DI.

Comment: @Telastyn Hm, you might have to be a bit more specific. I certainly don't think every project should have an IoC container, or that you should learn about them with the idea "this is what DI is". But in terms of answering Paul's specific question, I think they give the right idea, and can avoid dead-ends like adopting a service locator pattern.

Comment: At that point, it becomes fairly trivial to pass in a mock/fake service to provide you with your "online" data during testing.  it is easy to fake service.

Answer (score 37):

I would implement it like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    private ICloudService cloudService;

    public Foo(ICloudService s)
    {
       cloudService=s;
    }

    public int methodA()
    {
         int val = goOnlineToGetVal();

         return val;
    }

    private int goOnlineToGetVal()
    {
        int oval = cloudService.getValueFromService();
        return oval;
    }
}
```

The interface `ICloudService` can be either implemented with a mock for testing, or with the "real" cloudservice. When the instantiation `new CloudService()` is mandatory for every call of `getValueFromService`, or `CloudService`is from a 3rd party API which cannot be changed, implement a wrapper, deriving from `ICloudService` and making the appropriate calls.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go. There are class libraries that can mock an interface giving you absolute control of the test.